# What is a black sheep in Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, idiom, animals

It is easy to translate "black sheep" literally: *ovis nigra*.
I suspect that this phrase does not have the same meaning as in English (and Finnish), judging by its absence in literature — assuming my searches were correct.
Is there a Latin phrase that means a disreputable member in a group, preferably classical?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe *dedecus familiae*, the shame of or to the family (e.g. Cicero pro Cluentio).

C. D. Yonge [translates](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0019%3Atext%3DClu.%3Asection%3D16) Cicero's [original](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0010%3Atext%3DClu.%3Asection%3D16) *dedecus familiae* as "disgrace of his family", which is what a black sheep means.

Answer (score 5):

*superbis iuvenibus* the 'proud young men' (dative pl) are described as

> **siccis herbis** 'withered crops.' *(1310 - 20 de Lisle Psalter:)*

However, this is closer to "He's such a disappointment," than "The black sheep of the family." Alternatively,

**impius,** (3) undutiful  (Ainsworth & Mead)

> Filius impius in patrem *(Tacitus)*