# Is there a Latin idiom for in the doghouse?

Tags: idiom

In English if you are "in the doghouse" you are in disgrace.

From [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20the%20doghouse):

> in a bad situation because someone is angry at one : in trouble
> He's in the doghouse for forgetting his wife's birthday.

Is there a related Latin idiom?

Comment: Does [this question on an idiom for disgrace](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/972/79) help?

Comment: I added a better definition from M-W.