# How to call someone a disgrace or mistake?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

How would you call someone a mistake and/or a disgrace in Latin? long story short: I’m writing something and in this specific instance a character is being condemned, ridiculed and planned to be killed. I have a first part, the phrase “Respice finem” (consider the end) but need to add that extra “name calling” for emphasis. Also, if anyone has any ideas for a dramatic afterthought (in Latin of course) I would love to hear!

Comment: For most of Roman history, the paterfamilias (at least in theory) had the right and the responsibility to keep his family strong by killing unsuitable children. Is that the sort of "you're a mistake that should be killed" you're looking for?

Comment: Does [this thread](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/972/what-is-a-black-sheep-in-latin) answer your question?